# Hosting an already made Django website with Heroku

Tags: python, django, sqlite, postgresql, heroku

I have already finished my website made with Django and would like to put it up. I found Heroku and saw that is free for my basic needs and would like to host it there. My site uses SQLite not PostgreSQL so I would like to know how to use that since it doesn't support sqlite. I found the getting started with Django page on Heroku but I didn't use pip or virtualenv to set it up.

What steps should I follow to get my site up? Just FYI I am using latest Django dev branch 1.8 and Python 3.4.1 and it is a personal website.

Here is my settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '0r58%!j00w2q1faj*57=d)*fv^=ai#-wgnakj91^--z5f(ohq1'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "templates"),
    )

if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static-only")
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "media")
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static"),
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a requirements.txt with all your dependencies, because heroku uses that file to provide you the services you need.

After you added the postgreSQL add-on to your heroku project, heroku generates you a DATABASE_URL environment variable. you can parse that in your settings.py according to heroku's tutorial:

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

the basic wsgi.py is also provided in the tutorial, you can just use that.

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from dj_static import Cling

application = Cling(get_wsgi_application())
```

commit the application to your local git repository and push it to the heroku remote repository. if you do that on the console you'll get good feedback about your deployment.

basically you need to follow the [getting started tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django). skipping the virtual environment stuff just makes generating the requirements file more complicated, but it is possible.